# Vectorized way of using the previous row value based on the condition

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe as below. I want to perform the below condition:
if Column 'A' is 1 then update the value of column 'F' with the previous value of 'F'. This can be done row by row iteration but it is not efficient way of doing that. I want a vectorized method of doing that.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A':[1,1,1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0], 'C':[1,1,1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1], 'D':[1,1,1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1],
'F':[2,0,0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1]})
df

    A   C   D   F
0   1   1   1   2
1   1   1   1   0
2   1   1   1   0
3   0   0   0   0
4   0   0   0   0
5   0   0   0   1
6   1   1   1   1
7   0   1   1   1
8   0   1   1   1
```

My desired output:

```
    A   C   D   F
0   1   1   1   2
1   1   1   1   2
2   1   1   1   2
3   0   0   0   0
4   0   0   0   0
5   0   0   0   1
6   1   1   1   1
7   0   1   1   1
8   0   1   1   1
```

I tried the below code, but it doesnot work because when I use shift, it doesnot take the updated previous row.

```
df['F'] = df.groupby(['A'])['F'].shift(1)
df

    A   C   D   F
0   1   1   1   NaN
1   1   1   1   2.0
2   1   1   1   0.0
3   0   0   0   NaN
4   0   0   0   0.0
5   0   0   0   0.0
6   1   1   1   0.0
7   0   1   1   1.0
8   0   1   1   1.0
```

Answer (score 2):

#### `transform('first')`

```
df.F.groupby(df.A.rsub(1).cumsum()).transform('first')

0    2
1    2
2    2
3    0
4    0
5    1
6    1
7    1
8    1
Name: F, dtype: int64
```

---

Assign to column `'F'`

```
df.assign(F=df.F.groupby(df.A.rsub(1).cumsum()).transform('first'))

   A  C  D  F
0  1  1  1  2
1  1  1  1  2
2  1  1  1  2
3  0  0  0  0
4  0  0  0  0
5  0  0  0  1
6  1  1  1  1
7  0  1  1  1
8  0  1  1  1
```

Answer (score 1):

we also know how to do it without groupby:

```
where=df['A'].eq(1)&df['A'].ne(df['A'].shift())
df['F']=df['F'].where(where).ffill().mask(df['A'].ne(1),df['F'])
print(df)

   A  C  D    F
0  1  1  1  2.0
1  1  1  1  2.0
2  1  1  1  2.0
3  0  0  0  0.0
4  0  0  0  0.0
5  0  0  0  1.0
6  1  1  1  1.0
7  0  1  1  1.0
8  0  1  1  1.0
```